# scipy curve_fit scaling data

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting

I try to optimize the function with `scipy curve_fit`and then find maximum of it with `scipy minimize`

```
def func(x, a0, a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,
         a28,a29,a30,a31,a32,a33, pol_rate1, pol_rate2, pol_rate3,pol_rate4
):
    f = a0*sin(x[0])**pol_rate1 + a1*sin(x[1])**0.5 + a2*sin(x[2])**pol_rate4 + a3*x[3] + \
    a4*x[4] + a5*sin(x[5])**pol_rate2 + a6*x[6] + a7*x[7] + a8*sin(x[8])**pol_rate3

    return f
```

THe thing that I cant understand is that results of fitting (such as R squared) and the optimal values depend on the scale of my data.

For example, results for x, 2x and 10x are pretty much different. How can I define when results are really sustainable and trustworthing?

Comment: Remember that scaling `x` changes the *periodicities* of the sinusoids you're summing together rather than their amplitudes. You should expect the optimal weights on these sinusoidal components to change as you alter their periodicities.

Comment: @ali_m Interesting that the same thing happens to non sinusoids. If I remove sinus and leave just polynomial function then scaling will change results anyway. Could it be the result of very complex dependencies? In fact, I am trying to optimize 30 parameters

Comment: Broadly speaking, any type of manipulation that changes the range of different possible shapes that your functional approximation can take on can, at least in principle, result in a different set of fitted parameters and a different R² value

Comment: @ali_m But what is the correct result then? Is it possible to determine the best minimization scale ? If I want to find a minimum of some function, it will be different any time I change the scale